# Is there an equivalent for Chrome, of what XUL is for Mozilla?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, xul

XUL seems to be an API which enables you to create GUI based on Mozilla framework.

Can it also enable you to automate Firefox's GUI?

Which is the equivalent(s) for Chrome, that enables you to **both** create GUI's and automate Chrome's GUI?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one.

Extensions are Javascript. Chrome uses WebKit for rendering, so you'd use that to create a GUI.

Comment: As for manipulation Chrome GUI itself, and not what it renders?